# Can't append file in php

Tags: php, mysql, file

I'm trying to write any insert query that run from my program. But, when my code run, it not append the new insert query, instead, it rewrite the file. I still newbie in programming, please help me. It happen everytime I rerun the program, beside that, it will append the file.

Here is my insert function :

```
function insertInto($conn, $sql,$fp){
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    fwrite($fp, $sql."\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Here is the code to call that function

```
$fp = fopen('history_db_input.txt', 'w');
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
fwrite($fp, "\n$date\n");
insertInto($conn,"INSERT INTO `link_promo`(`id`, `promo_id`, `linpro_link`) VALUES ('','1','$nama[$indeks]')",$fp);
```

Hope you guys can help me. Actually, the function in separate file, just for the information.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have opened the file in `w` mode, which is write only. You can change this by setting

```
$fp = fopen('history_db_input.txt', 'w');
```

to

```
$fp = fopen('history_db_input.txt', 'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `$fp = fopen('history_db_input.txt', 'a+');` too.